# Why can Tobi not just use space-time ninjutsu to capture Bee and Naruto?

Tags: naruto

Since Obito can travel through space-time, I wonder why he didn't just teleport to all those jinchuuriki? He could then easily bring them to an Akatsuki hideout where the combined force of them could capture them without others interfering.

Comment: He would have to know where exactly the Jinchuuriki are and have that place marked or else he wouldn't be able to teleport there.

Comment: Well, it would be a good start to teleport into their villages. Then the chances are high to find them there.
But what else besides the unknown whereabouts hinders him from doing so?

Comment: I get the feeling he could have, though it would have been very difficult since they are both very powerful and frequently under watch, especially in the village. He would be unable to restrain them since his genjutsu would not be very effective, so no matter what he would have a fight on his hands. His best hope would be when they are out of the village, but he has to find them first, and then be able to actually fight anyone guarding him as well.

Comment: @Ms.Steel Obito don't need to mark places to teleport. You're mistaking his jutsu with 4th Hokage's.

Comment: @AyaseEri maybe, but I'm pretty sure he even said he had to have the place marked or else he couldn't teleport there.

Comment: I believe it was he has to know the place before he can teleport to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is because of the nature of his jutsu. His jutsu works by moving whole or part of his body into the other space. His jutsu has a weakness in that the bigger the object he is transporting, the longer the time needed for him to do it. This was noted by Konan and was mentioned during the fight between Konan and Tobi when the latter was about to retrieve the Rinnegan from Nagato's corpse. If I remember correctly, to move his entire body he needs about 5 seconds.

Now add another person to the equation and you get 10 whole seconds before he can do the jutsu successfully. 10 seconds next to a Jinchuuriki that knows you're going to kill him. There's no way they're just going to sit tight and enjoy the trip. So this makes kidnapping the Jinchuuriki and ganging up on them at the hideout like you're suggesting as an impossible thing to do.